# Reduction of the dataset in R - filtering and grouping?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
  Country   Partner   Year   Sector    Value
1     AUT      AUT    2005        A     2132
2     AUT      AUT    2005        B    43213
3     AUT      AUT    2006        A     2451
4     AUT      AUT    2006        B    38723
5     AUT      AUS    2005        A     3241
6     AUT      AUS    2005        B    24213
7     AUT      AUS    2006        A     3728
8     AUT      AUS    2006        B    21923
9     AUS      AUT    2005        A      723
10    AUS      AUT    2005        B    23120
11    AUS      AUT    2006        A      953
...
```

What I would like to get is the following data formats ):

a) The total output of a Country/Year/Sector, regardless of the Partner

```
  Country    Year   Sector    Value
1     AUT    2005        A   231435
2     AUT    2005        B  4512312
3     AUT    2006        A   213451
4     AUT    2006        B  4738723
5     AUS    2005        A   123461
6     AUS    2005        B  3213456
7     AUS    2006        A   162134
...
```

b) Domestic use of the Country/Year/Sector

```
  Country   Partner   Year   Sector    Value
1     AUT      AUT    2005        A     2132
2     AUT      AUT    2005        B    43213
3     AUT      AUT    2006        A     2451
4     AUT      AUT    2006        B    38723
5     AUS      AUS    2005        A     3241
6     AUS      AUS    2005        B    24213
7     AUS      AUS    2006        A     2314  
...
```

There are some other data formats that I will need but as they seem analogous, I won't include them, and they should prove as a useful exercise for me once I grasp the idea of how to get to a) and b).

As to what I have already tried - I am a beginner so not much: I tried to play with the `tidyr` functions `filter`, `group_by` I was also trying to `spread` and `gather` which worked in some similar cases but here it does not.

I have a suspicion that some kind of a loop might be useful here, but that is not my strength yet, to say the least.

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Looks like you need some grouping and summarizing. Try this for (a) : `dt %>%
  group_by(Country, Year, Sector) %>%
  summarise(Value = sum(Value)) %>%
  ungroup()`. Not sure how (b) works as it has exactly the same columns as your initial dataset.

Comment: I had a second thought about (b). Do you just need this? `dt %>% filter(Country == Partner)`

Comment: Worked lovely, thank you!